# How to edit few lines in a column using awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a ascii data file e.g.:

```
ifile.txt
2
3
2
3
4
5
6
4
```

I would like to multiply 3 into all the numbers after 6th line. So outfile will be:

```
ofile.txt
2
3
2
3
4
15
18
12
```

my algorithm/ script is

```
awk '{if ($1<line 6); printf "%10.5f\n", $1}' ifile.txt > ofile.txt
awk '{if ($1>=line 6); printf "%10.5f\n", $1*3}' ifile.txt >> ofile.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
awk 'NR > 6 { $1 *= 3 } 1' ifile.txt
```

Multiply the first field by 3 when the record (line) number `NR` is greater than 6.

The structure of an awk program is `condition { action }`, where the default condition is *true* and the default action is `{ print }`, so the `1` at the end is the shortest way of always printing every line.

Comment: @Kayan hopefully my explanatory paragraph makes it clear that you would replace the `1` with a block that used `printf`. It wasn't clear from your desired output that you required any formatting.